# How to read values from CFG file and then put them in PHP array for later comparing

Tags: php, file

I have the CFG file stored somewhere on the host with defined path.
I want to open that file read all values from that file, and then convert them into PHP array for later comparing with another strings. 
The file i got is like this

```
echo Executing Server Config...

//podesuvanja na serverot
rcon_password promeni
rcon 0
hostname Demo
weburl www.demo.com 
password
language demo

gamemode0 grandlarc 1

//filterskripti
filterscripts base gl_actions gl_property gl_realtime

   plugins
mapname Demo
language Demo

maxnpc 0
onfoot_rate 40
incar_rate 40
weapon_rate 40
stream_distance 100.0
stream_rate 900
ackslimit 3000

announce 1
query 1
lanmode 0
maxplayers 1
port 7777
```

I want to get the value from `port` and then compare to another variable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$contents=file_get_contents('filename');` then `preg_match('/port\s([0-9]{4})/', $contents, $match)`

Comment: Consider using [INI file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) and [PHP parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php).

Comment: Thanks to  ArtisticPhonex it works but now i have another problem the file I want to read is from another user on the same web server (VPS)